# Larger normal vectors for PCL visualization

Tags: c++, boost, visualization, point-cloud-library, point-clouds

I am using `NormalEstimation<PointXYZ, Normal>` to compute the normals for `PointCloud<PointXYZ>` and get `PointCloud<PointNormal>`. Afterwards, I use `addPointCloudNormals<PointXYZ, Normal>()` for my visualization to put the points and their normal vectors together.

My visualization works, and I can see normal vectors corresponding the points in space. However they are too small and I was wondering if there is a way of making them more visible. An example to more visible normal vectors could be found at the official tutorials http://pointclouds.org/documentation/tutorials/normal_estimation.php

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I realized that increasing the `scale` argument of `addPointCloudNormals` is doing sort of what I was looking for even though it does not exactly increase the volume of arrows similar to those shown in the tutorial.